# What overhead does garbage collection logging add to the JVM?

Tags: java, performance

Does the JVM switches -XX:+PrintGCDetails and/or -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps add any significant overhead to the JVM. Better stated, is there situations when you would not add these switches to your JAVA_OPTS?

Comment: I'd say that if it's a real issue for you (and not just a question out of curiosity), you should measure it on your setup, with a "typical" workload.  It's very hard to (meaningfully) generalize about GC performance.

Comment: It is not a issue but our vendor recommend us not to use it. I wanted to get more information before I argued the point with them. I usually add those setting to existing servers since from what I have read it is low overhead and gives us another data point for fault analysis. And our app has lots of faults.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of 'significant overhead'?

Yes, they do add overhead. Exactly how much depends on a number of factors, not in the least the number of GCs your application has.

We don't add those switches by default, not in the least because there are better ways of gathering GC information.

Comment: What I mean is, do those switches add more overhead that it is worth. From my reading it does add overhead, but it is still recommended to gather those statistics in a production environment.

Comment: I'd recommend it if you suspect there's a problem. There are better ways of gathering 'normal' statistics. But in the end, whether or not it's worth it is a judgment call I can't make for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

They don't add that much overhead at all, but I still wouldn't run with them in PROD.  Analyzing GC behavior is something that is best done in a testing environment where you can control the load to explore various aspects of the application, including GC efficiency.  I might add them (well, I'd probably use a different tool) in PROD iff there is a problem with the app and I have reason to believe GC is involved. And once I've captured a sufficient amount of data, I'd pull it out.